# Optimize Lookup Performance, MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance

I am relatively new to databasing; so sorry if this is 101 knowledge that I haven't soaked up yet.  I googled but found no satisfying answer.

I am writing a program that walks through ~20mio files and puts their file names all in one table (I have strong preferences of keeping it in one table for future use).  Each `file_name` contains a BIGINT `id` (among other Ascii characters).  There are only about 20 `file_name`s for each BIGINT `id`.  My question now:  **Can I leverage this name structure for better lookup performance?**

My table structure so far:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS files
        (file_name VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET ascii NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
        id BIGINT UNSIGNED,
        ...)
```

And my lookup statements are just:

```
WHERE file_name = '...'
```

Is it, for example, better to index `id` and then look up `file_name` and `id`?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: To judge the "lookup performance", let's see the `SELECT` statements.

Comment: What is `id` for?  How is it computed?  Do you really need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you can have 20 different filenames for each ID so ID is not unique. Then you can't use the ID for the Primary Key. 
The only option is to use file_name as the Primary Key if you know that the file_name is unique. This would give you the max performance if you look for a specific file_name. 
If you also need to look for all the files with a specific ID you must create a Not Unique Index on the ID field.

Comment: Naming a column ID and then not store a PK in it will be mightily confusing for anyone making sense out the table.

Answer (score 1):

The usual table design would be to let id be the PRIMARY KEY. If you want to query for file_name as well , an index on that column may be the right choice.

Comment: Cool.  Thanks a lot for your quick answer.  `file_name` is actually the only thing that is of importance to me.  `id` is just something that I am thinking about leveraging; hence the question and your answer.
Quick question, though:  How big of a performance hit will I take if I index `file_name` on top of PK `id`?

Comment: ~20mio rows make an index certainly very worth using, especially when the index is unique. So you will very likely find your file magnitudes faster with index compared to without. You pay with the index size. Things become tricky and slow when the index does not fit any more in the memory of the database. make sure the db has enough RAM.

Comment: @luksch - if the table is InnoDB, then the `PRIMARY KEY` is clustered with the data, hence takes no extra space.  A _secondary_ `INDEX(id)` would cost a bunch of space, possibly more than the table itself.